# Uknown file encoding

Tags: encoding, hex

So, I'm trying to find out the encoding of some files. The problem is, that I've tryed all available encodings and none gave me readable result.

I can open the file like this:

```
4e46 5353 0401 0100 3419 c517 a3fe 37cc
7fec df41 1e3f 0b49 5546 4b5d c443 0300
ae81 3aac 461a 6bc2 bbd3 d80a 2377 9656
9275 f466 5cac c0f0 acb3 40e5 b61b f9e4
00ee 8b48 caed 7b74 f95c 78e0 998c 4be0
09c8 08a4 8810 a023 026d 1b91 836c 5f12
ebc4 b2c7 4625 c351 a607 4f7d 5e0e 75ed
395f fecc b337 7f72 7ce7 8d72 a43f 8a69
14ef 570c 2be2 cd70 d80f 64d4 3043 4862
f89b 81af 3d56 0f0b b600 14aa c4ec 773b
56b4 44ee f82b 1d5b 8053 8560 5123 4693
```

or like this:

```
NFSS 4ЕЈю7МмЯA?IUFK]ДC ®Ѓ:¬FkВ»УШ
#w–V’uфf\¬Ар¬і@е¶щд о‹HКн{tщ\xа™ЊKа    И¤€ #m‘ѓl_лДІЗF%ГQ¦O}^uн9_юМі7r|зЌr¤?ЉiпW+вНpШdФ0CHbш›ЃЇ=V¶ ЄДмw;VґDош+[ЂS…`Q#F“S¶фЯgЪ;CYД-і‹Лљ{ЎЋС†”9?[„_=>ћ’вQэЅч%Ї¬QГєѓ)AЃЗi .®я®g®‘ ЅW_—2І=y#Ъ·"¦ЋxДґ†%Жчб~‰™эЎd3}~f·Ёк‰ЙНх>ЊнПVЎЮBк;€¤TCкЫя‡·W·
‚iзИќT(¬™§2ІeR=љ3@oфПҐЄыя Єђ (Gњ»Џњ‹бґ(Ќ[°§
```

I've uploaded some other files to google drive. All of them have the same beginning: NFSS (It's NFS game save file). https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17nXVo_cHu2jKtRAdKAEhLuPbmMW5CuaY?usp=sharing

So, can anybody detect the encoding? And explain how to do it?

Comment: There's a good chance that this is simply some proprietary format that the NFS devs decided on to store their data. Unless they use some common format or library internally you'll probably have to go full-on reverse-engineering to find out how it's structured (i.e. create two similar save files and find out the difference. Repeat until all relevant information is known).

Comment: Yeah, seems like that. That's sad. I wanted to code "saves organaizer" which represents saved data in more friendly formate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file command.
`file -i` gives you some usefull info in these cases:

> 636468866: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

However as pointed by joachim-sauer this is the fallback and provides nothing.

Comment: That "useful info" is just the fallback: it's not one of the known file format.s